# Unity Admob Ads doesn't appear in some projects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know this is so similar topic to others but I need help about that and I couldn't find any solution since 3 days. I found a guide for Unity Admob Ads and I applied it. It works on the project that I new created. But doesn't appear on my existed project, I checked all layers,cameras etc. but couldn't find any mistake.

I'll attach a video here, about what I exactly did (1.30 min);https://youtu.be/pLpQWHvYMDk

End of this video, I installed the apk to my device and ads doesn't appear.

My english is bad, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have a few theories.

First, Admob is based on auctions. Which means that they will sell your ads to the best bid. Your app is still in configuration phase to them and that is the reason that is not showing.

Second, if you are testing on the editor, ads will never show up. You have to test on your phone (not recommended to click on this ads, you can lose your account).

Third, I don't use admob but are you sure that everything is created and set properly on the admob dashboard? There is no "test mode" active?

I highly recommend using the official unity pluggin by google: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity

The docummentation is well-made and everything should work great.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I'm doing the same things for another new created project and looks fine. Everything is working. I think the problem is from layers, project settings etc.